# Как лучше хранить временные данные в пайтон?

Tags: python, django

Я пишу приложение на django и у меня возник вопрос, каким способом лучше хранить временные данные(массив). У меня после того, как модератор начал работу создается словарь с данными(id товара, id модератора ...) и эту штукенцию нужно хранить какое-то время, а когда будет нужно прочитать и удалить. Я пробовал использовать Temporary file, но как я понял он не подходит для моих задач, так как там плохо с построчной записью а затем с построчным чтением. Хранение временного файла в БД... я не думаю что это хороший вариант, но у меня django так что такое делать не проблема. Есть так же case: просто создать словарь в коде и его использовать как временное хранилище(если что случится, то эти данные не жалко), а может использовать текстовый файл для этих целей?

Comment: «Какое-то время» это сколько? Насколько критична случайная потеря этих данных?

Comment: @andreymal, какое-то время. это максимум 30 минут, время будет ограничено( у меня максимальное время работы модератора над одним товаром 30 минут), а потеря данных будет не особо критична, это просто информация о том, кто какой товар в данный момент модерирует

Comment: Тогда положить в любую in-memory базу данных, например redis или memcached

Comment: @andreymal, хорошо, спасибо